# Powershell, ie9 and getElementById

Tags: powershell, internet-explorer-9, getelementbyid

I use successfully a script for web automation from this site: [heise web automation](http://www.heise.de/ct/projekte/machmit/webautomatisieren/wiki/SkriptNeue)

I know it is in german, but perhaps someone can help.

The important part of the e-plus website:

```
    <tr>
        <td class="td1">Benutzername:</td>
        <td class="space"><img src="/img/c.gif" alt="" /></td>
        <td class="td2"><input type="text" id="IDToken1OL" name="IDToken1" onfocus="setToken(this)" onblur="getToken(this)" value="Benutzername" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="td1">Passwort:</td>
        <td class="space"><img src="/img/c.gif" alt="" /></td>
        <td class="td2"><input type="password" id="IDToken2OL" name="IDToken2" onfocus="setToken(this)" onblur="getToken(this)" value="" class="passwortFake" /></td>
    </tr>
```

the part of the Powershell script:

```
$script:ie = New-Object -comobject InternetExplorer.Application
$ie.visible = $false
$ie.silent = $true
#
$ie.Navigate("https://www.eplus.de/login/login.asp")
LadenWarten(1)
#
$ie.Document.getElementById("IDToken1OL").value = $user
$ie.Document.getElementById("IDToken2OL").value = $passwort
$ie.Document.getElementsByTagName("a") | foreach {
    if ($_.href -eq "javascript:SSO_Submit()") {
        $_.Click()
    }
}
```

the getElementById worked for ie8 but now I have updated to ie9 and it is not working anymore.

the errormessage:

```
+ $ie.Document.getElementById <<<< ("IDToken1OL").value = $user
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodCountCouldNotFindBest
```

the count of the arguments is wrong.

all I was able to find was a hint, that in ie9 getElementById changed.

can anybody help?

Thanks, David

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When automating only one concrete site (and the script is not generic or any site) you can try to set compatibility view in IE settings (Tools -> Compatibility View settings). IE should switch to IE8 view when browsing the site.

Comment: Cool, thanks that helped. I added the site to the list of websites for compatibility view

Comment: For IE11 on Server 2012 R2 This did not work, for me. I found [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28723314/powershell-internet-explorer-automation-error-server-2012) to work. However form my experience, you have to do this for each page you touch.

Answer (score 3):

See http://www.experts-exchange.com/Web_Development/Web_Languages-Standards/Q_27920160.html --

Quoted:
"I should've used member invocation:

```
$ie = new-object -com "InternetExplorer.Application"
$ie.navigate("about:blank")
$doc = $ie.Document

$element = [System.__ComObject].InvokeMember(“getElementById”,[System.Reflection.BindingFlags]::InvokeMethod, $null, $doc, $id)
```

and for getElementsByTagName:

```
$elements = @([System.__ComObject].InvokeMember(“getElementsByTagName”,[System.Reflection.BindingFlags]::InvokeMethod, $null, $doc, $tagname))
```

"

Answer (score 0):

Example of using querySelector:

```
  $element = [System.__ComObject].InvokeMember("querySelector",[System.Reflection.BindingFlags]::InvokeMethod, $null, $ie.Document, "$QueryHere")
```