# querySelectorAll of IE COM does not work in IE 8

Tags: internet-explorer, powershell, com, internet-explorer-8, powershell-2.0

I'm accessing the `InternetExplorer.Application` COM through Powershell. I'm trying to use the `querySelector` of the `document`, but it doesn't return any result. I'm currently using IE8.

```
$ie = New-Object -com "InternetExplorer.Application"
$ie.visible = $true
$ie.Navigate("www.google.com")


if ($ie.Busy) { Start-Sleep 1 }

# This statement works
@($ie.Document.getElementsByTagName("a"))[0]

# This statement doesn't work, though querySelectorAll 
# exist in the document object
@($ie.Document.querySelectorAll("a"))[0]

# I tried this
$ie.Document.querySelectorAll("a") -eq $null # evaluates to True
```

Comment: What error message do you get ? what does it return ?

Comment: `querySelectorAll` doesn't return anything. It return null.

Comment: Tried your code on my machine and got: "Method invocation failed because [mshtml.HTMLDocumentClass] doesn't contain a method named 'querySelectorAll'."

Comment: @DavidBrabant are you using IE 8? querySelectorAll [appeared](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_core.html) in IE8

Comment: @DavidBrabant I added `if ($ie.Busy) { Start-Sleep 1 }` to ensure the page loads. before accessing the `Document`.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [IDocumentSelector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288530) prefix to reference the method, using something like this:

```
$ie.Document.IDocumentSelector_querySelectorAll("a")
```

There are [one](http://poshcode.org/561) or [two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6065359/powershell-ie9-and-getelementbyid) powershell browser API troubleshooting resources which may help. [Sizzle](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=823) may help if the [doctype](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=2202) is causing the browser to render is almost standards or quirks modes, which do not support querySelectorAll.

Comment: `$ie.Document.IDocumentSelector_querySelectorAll("a")` didn't worked. Anyway, I haven't explored the links you've post. I'll try to look on them on weekend.

Comment: I need a css selector function to search beyond simple id or name element name. Hmmm, Sizzle may do the trick. Anyway, I'll try it within this week.