# Cannot find an overload for "getElementById" and the argument count: "1"

Tags: internet-explorer, powershell

I'm getting this error in a simple PowerShell script. "getElementByID" always takes 1 argument, so I'm not sure why this is failing. I'm using IE 11 and PowerShell 3 running on WS2K8 r2.

```
$ie = New-Object -com InternetExplorer.Application 
$ie.visible=$true
$ie.navigate("http://duckduckgo.com") 
while($ie.ReadyState -ne 4) {start-sleep -m 100}
$ie.document.getElementById("search_form_input_homepage").value = "foobar"
$ie.document.getElementById("search_button_homepage").Click()
```

resulting error message:

> Cannot find an overload for "getElementById" and the argument count:
>   "1". At C:\SCRIPTS\sample.ps1:5 char:1
>   + $ie.document.getElementById("search_form_input_homepage").value = "foobar"
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodCountCouldNotFindBest

Comment: Your code works under IE 11 and Windows 7 x64. So maybe it's a security issue?

Comment: good suggestion - I tried disabling IE Enhanced Security Configuration for Admins and Users both, but no luck. maybe there's something else security-related I could try?

Comment: Found this on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12733143/powershell-system-comobject-document-property-no-longer-works-under-ie-9

Comment: so far I've tried cumulatively (1) disabling IE ESC (2) disabling protected mode for the Internet Zone (3) running powershell as administrator - all to no avail.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks SiZiIOUS for the link - eventually that led me to try testing for null references - it seems that during the redirect from HTTP to HTTPS at least *some* part of the COM object is "lost".

After resetting things back to defaults (including Internet Zone security settings), it appears that the two things I need to do to get this to work *without* running PowerShell as administrator are:

1. Disable IE Enhanced Security Configuration
2. Add the desired URL to Compatibility View

Also worth noting - if after this I add the URL to Trusted Sites, it actually *stops* working again, which I suspect caused me to miss the solution at some point previously since when I tried this combination of settings it was probably listed in Trusted Sites. Why that would be, I'm not sure, but maybe it will spark a thought for someone who can explain.