# Powershell website login automation

Tags: powershell

I am attempting to automate logging in to a website. My below code works on my 2 Windows 10 machines but on my Win2K12r2 test environment, it errors with the following Error at each getElementById call.

> Cannot find an overload for "getElementById" and the argument count: "1".

```
$username = "MY-USER" 
$password = "MY-PASS" 
$ie = New-Object -com InternetExplorer.Application 
$ie.visible=$true
$ie.navigate("https://www.WEBSITE.com/login") 
while($ie.ReadyState -ne 4) {start-sleep -m 100} 
$ie.document.getElementById("userid").value= "$username" 
$ie.document.getElementById("password").value = "$password" 
$ie.document.getElementById("loginbutton").click()
start-sleep 20 
$ie.navigate("https://www.WEBSITE.com/logout") 
start-sleep 5
$ie.quit()
```

What am I missing on the Server OS?

- IE Enhanced Security Protection is disabled
- Compatibility Mode did nothing but cause more errors
- 'Run As Admin' changed nothing

Comment: Might be [related to https](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24660691/cannot-find-an-overload-for-getelementbyid-and-the-argument-count-1), so try adding the address as a trusted site.