# About $ie.Document.getElementById

Tags: internet-explorer, powershell

I wrote a script to parse a HTML file. I have three machines, Windows 8.1, Windows Server 2012, and Windows Server 2008.

I use the COM object and method `$ie.Document.getElementById()` to get element in HTML file. The script runs without any problem in Windows 8.1, but is not working in Windows Server 2012 and Windows Server 2008. It shows `$ie.Document` is null object.

I searched for a while and found that there is a bug with COM object. So I imported manually Microsoft.mshtml.dll, now script runs well in win server 2012, but still not working under win server 2008. I can see all properties by using `$ie.document | Get-Member`, but the object `$ie.Document` is always null.

Comment: Did you check that MS Server 2008 is running the same version of Powershell? (use `$PSVersionTable` or `Get-Host` to test that)

Comment: @JGreenwell My Powershell is at version 2.0, and I cannot upgrade it because the server holds all website traffic and cannot be stopped. I'm confused because by adding the dll library it should work.

Comment: GetElementbyId seems not to have a problem with Powershell 2.0 and IE 9+ (tried a working script using `powershell ./testscript.ps1 -version '2.0'` and got that same error: See [this question for a possible workaround on 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12733143/powershell-system-comobject-document-property-no-longer-works-under-ie-9)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12733143/powershell-system-comobject-document-property-no-longer-works-under-ie-9) question. There is some sort of a bug in IE. Installing office fixed this problem for me. YMMV.