# Can't use InternetExplorer.Application object?

Tags: internet-explorer, powershell

I have an entire code file that works flawlessly on a PC. I brought it over to another one, and it busted. I used this snippet, and the output is just blank, it's not getting anything from the object. The browser does load the page though.

```
# Create the IE com object 
"Lauching IE process..."
$ie = new-object -com InternetExplorer.Application 
$ie.visible = $true
# Navigate to the login page
"Opening $loginPage"
$ie.navigate($loginPage) 
"Waiting for page to load..."
# Wait for the page to finish loading 
do {sleep 2} until (-not ($ie.Busy)) 
sleep 2
$ie.document.body.innerHTML
```

I found some references to IE security models, running as Admin, etc, and fiddled with it a bit.

- Script doesn't work if I run it as Administrator
- I've disabled as much IE security as possible
- Downgraded from IE 11 to IE 9

Still no luck.

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: Where is `$loginPage` defined?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay I ended up solving the issue. Based on this post :

[Powershell System.__ComObject.document property no longer works under IE 9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12733143/powershell-system-comobject-document-property-no-longer-works-under-ie-9)

I also noticed that

```
$ie.document | Get-Member
```

Showed a COM object guid on the broken machine, and mshtml on the good machine. The good machine did indeed have Office installed. I copied

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft.NET\Primary Interop Assemblies\microsoft.mshtml.dll
```

to the broken machine. Then at the top of my script I added

```
Add-Type -Path "C:\dll\Microsoft.mshtml.dll"
```

And bingo, the script now works as expected!

Comment: Dude! I can't believe this works! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you have stored inside of your $loginPage variable, so i replaced it with www.google.com and it opened the page, but did not display the .document.body.html portion.

I found this a forum that discussed a similar issue to what you are describing. They recommended changing the code to

```
$ie = new-object -com internetexplorer.application 
$ie.Visible = $true
$ie.navigate('https://www.google.com')
while($ie.busy){Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 100}
$ie.document.body | select innerhtml
```

I tried this and it worked fine.

reference: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/scriptcenter/en-US/2faea229-a114-4d58-9624-f1ee42404928/powershell-internetexplorerapplication-things-are-missing?forum=ITCG