# When using Invoke-WebRequest Why can I only connect to certain URLs if I use UseBasicParsing?

Tags: powershell, invoke-webrequest

I am iterating through a CSV file of URLs and using Invoke-WebRequest to get back the innerHTML and href values for links that match a specified criteria however this only works for some URLs and not for others unless I add the parameter -UseBasicParsing which doesn't provide the property access and filtering capabilities I need.

A common denominator is that the ones that don't work all use a www subdomain but a couple of them are still accessible without this but still don't work and I am not sure this should be an issue anyway as other www URLs do work

As mentioned above, I have tried adding UseBasicParsing which does allow a connection but this restricts the data that I have access to. I have also looked at the http headers for the URLS to try and understand what the differences are but am unsure what the issue is.

This functions correctly and returns the innerHTML text and href for each link on the page

```
$currentRequest = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri https://moz.com/learn/seo/what- 
is-seo
$currentRequest | Get-Member
$currentRequest = $currentRequest.Links |
Select innerHTML, href |
WHERE innerHTML -like *SEO*
$currentRequest
```

Using exactly the same code with the following URL, the console just freezes until the script is exited

https://www.redevolution.com/what-is-seo

When I run the script with the working URL I get a pair of values for each link as shown below

```
innerHTML : Recommended SEO Companies
href      : https://moz.com/community/recommended
```

With the non working URL as mentioned above the command line just stays at a blinking cursor.

This is just one example and I need to query other data as well so it would be great to understand how I can consistently run Invoke-WebRequest without issues.

Many thanks!!

Mike

Comment: How long have you waited for the blinking cursor? What does your CPU usage look like during that time? I suspect the issue lies squarely with the content of the page and IE's ability to parse it.

Comment: I've left it for around 15minutes.  Will check cpu usage but it is a pretty basic page.

Answer (score 1):

Not so much an answer, as a long comment...

In PowerShell 5.1, Invoke-WebRequest uses the Internet Explorer engine to parse the html into a DOM, which can also cause execution of any scripts on the page, so it's possible something is going wrong in the script, or the headless Internet Explorer instance doesn't like the page content for whatever reason.

There are other reports elsewhere the same problem - for example [Invoke-WebRequest hangs in some cases, unless -UseBasicParsing is used](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/2812)

Adding the `-UseBasicParsing` switch bypasses Internet Explorer and uses a much simpler internal HTML parser - if you need to extract additional information you can use a HTML parser library like the [HtmlAgilityPack](https://html-agility-pack.net/) or [AngleSharp](https://github.com/AngleSharp/AngleSharp) to parse and query the `$currentRequest.Content` property.

Note that PowerShell Core 6.0 and up have made the `-UseBasicParsing` switch the default behaviour and there's effectively no way to turn it off, so if you want to write future-proof scripts now it's probably best to find a way to solve your problem using `-UseBasicParsing` so you dont have to rewrite it if / when you want to move up to PowerShell Core. (See [Breaking Changes for PowerShell 6.0 -> Changes to Web Cmdlets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/whats-new/breaking-changes-ps6?view=powershell-6#changes-to-web-cmdlets))

See [How to parse html in Powershell Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56777597/how-to-parse-html-in-powershell-core) for a related question.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, in the code that "works", i.e your first sample code, you are missing -UseBasicParsing. Now, why this is the case. Documentation here explains why: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-webrequest?view=powershell-5.1

To quote: "By default, script code in the web page may be run when the page is being parsed to populate the ParsedHtml property. Use the -UseBasicParsing switch to suppress this."

If you look at PowerShell v6, the default parsing has been switched to "-UseBasicParsing" (See here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-webrequest?view=powershell-6)

It is not great, b/c of the reasons you mentioned and unfortunately there is no relief coming (see the comment from PowerShell dev here: https://twitter.com/Steve_MSFT/status/1153456742719639552?s=20)