# getElementById does not seem to work in IE10

Tags: powershell, internet-explorer-10, getelementbyid

I have the following PowerShell code that works fine on a machine with PowerShell 2.0 and IE 8, but does not work on a separate machine with IE 10.

```
$ie = new-object -com "InternetExplorer.Application"
$ie.visible=$true
$ie.Navigate("http://localhost/website/")
While ($ie.busy) {Sleep 2}
$doc = $ie.document
$autobutton = $doc.getElementById("IdName").Click()
```

The HTML code I'm attempting to access looks something like this:

```
<input type="radio" id="IdName" checked value="true" />
```

And here is the error I'm getting when running the PowerShell code above on the machine with IE 10:

*"You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression."*

Does IE 10 not support *getElementById*? Do I need modify my script to handle IE 10 differently so that the button gets clicked?

**NOTE:** the server with IE 10 also has PowerShell 3, and so I've tried using *Invoke-WebRequest* as well, but that doesn't seem to help either (get same error).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Works for me on Win7 SP1 with IE10 and PowerShell V3.  I can find elements by ID using getElementByID().  However Click() is a method.  Does it return anything?  You may be getting null assigned to $autobutton.  Did you want the Click function instead e.g. `$autobutton = $doc.getElementById("IdName").Click`?

Comment: I still get the same error using the Click function or even without the Click. And not sure if it matters but the machine is Server 2008 R2 SP1.

Comment: Which specific line of code is giving that error?  If it is that last line, then are you sure $doc isn't null?

Comment: Hmm...$doc is returning null if I use Invoke-WebRequest, but does not return null if I use new-object -com "InternetExplorer.Application" and $ie.Navigate. Either way I still get the same error above. And the line of code throwing the error is the last line: $autobutton = $doc.getElementById("IdName").Click

Comment: Ack! I think I found the problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6065359/powershell-ie9-and-getelementbyid?rq=1.  Anyway, I think I'm good to go now after making the settings changes in IE.