# PowerShell internet explorer automation error server 2012

Tags: internet-explorer, powershell, windows-server-2012-r2

I have a PowerShell script that logs into one of our sites, clicks some links then closes. Basically just to monitor and make sure everything works ok! below is a snippet from the top of the script.

```
$ie = new-object -com "InternetExplorer.Application"
$ie.visible = $true
$ie.navigate($url)
while( $ie.busy){Start-Sleep 1} 
$doc = $ie.document
$continue = $doc.getElementByID("overridelink")
$continue.click()
while( $ie.busy){Start-Sleep 1}
```

Basically this section opens IE and clicks continue button for certificate error. If i run this on my windows 7 machine it works fine, however on Server 2012 R2 i get:

*"You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression"*

Both desktop and server are running PowerShell 4.0 and Internet explorer 11.

I read something a while back that mentioned this may be a bug in 2012 where it doesn't allow this method to click links in IE but cant remember where and if there was a fix!

Does anyone know what causes this and maybe how to resolve it?

another thing i was thinking(if anyone can be bothered to explain!), should i be using invoke-webrequest instead? if so is it possible to log into a site, open some links(doesn't have to be visible on screen) then close confirming it all works?

Thanks in advance for any input!

Answer (score 1):

Just enable the Internet Explorer Enterprise Mode.

In Internet Explorer, Press "ALT" key, go to Tools > Enterprise Mode.

If Enterprise Mode is not available:
•Launch GPEDIT.MSC
•Go to User Configuration > Administrative Templates > Windows Components > Internet Explorer > Let users turn on and use Enterprise Mode from the Tools menu 
•enabled

and it work !

Comment: I've tried disabling enhanced security, adding site to trusted sites, adding site to compatibility view list. But this is what finally did the trick. Thank you!

Comment: Additionally, since I was navigating through the site, I had to set Enterprise mode for each page I touched.